JordanDecomposition gives out different answers on symbolic and numerical calculations

Numerical substitution before or after performing the JordanDecomposition yields different results.
Here is the source code to reproduce the error:
rule = {a11 -> 1, a12 -> 4, a13 -> 3, h -> 2, a33 -> 5};
A = {{a11, a12, a13}, h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}};
{a, b} = JordanDecomposition[A];
b /. rule // MatrixForm
B = A /. rule;
{a1, b1} = JordanDecomposition[B];
b1 // MatrixForm


For symbolic input your get generic answer, which didn't account for possible specific relations of the symbolic coefficients. Therefore your should not expect the same answer in general.

For h->4 and h->-4 and h->1/10 both results are the same. For each value of h the matrix A is degenerate.

@Acus: Can you kindly give a reference to your claim "For symbolic input your get generic answer, which didn't account for possible specific relations of the symbolic coefficients"? I don't find it in the documentation.

When you work with symbolic coefficients a general assumption is that these symbols are generic. For example suppose you have matrix {{a,b},{c,d}} and ask if it is diagonalizable. The answer will be True. However, if you substitute values say, a->1,b->1, c->0,d->1 you get, of course, non diagonalizable (defectve) matrix. That is what I have in mind: Answer for symbolic input assume a generic case. What means generic is quite difficult to explain, but roughly you can understand it as  "not yielding problems" :-).

@Acus: Thank you for your example. Can you explain why the case h->2 is not generic?`

@user64494, you have to clear the variables with Clear[a, b, c, d], then it returns True as given by Acus.

@Domen: Thank you for your valuable remark.

This is a realization of the @Acus' idea. Let us consider
rule = {a11 -> 1, a12 -> 4, a13 -> 3, h -> 2, a33 -> 5};
A = {{a11, a12, a13}, h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}};

and its characteristic polynomial before and after applying rule.
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x] == 0, x]


{{x -> 0}, {x ->  1/2 (a11 + a33 +  a12 h - \[Sqrt]((a11 + a33 + a12 h)^2 +  4 (a13^2 - a11 a33 - a12 a33 h + a13^2 h^2)))}, {x ->  1/2 (a11 + a33 +  a12 h + \[Sqrt]((a11 + a33 + a12 h)^2 +  4 (a13^2 - a11 a33 - a12 a33 h + a13^2 h^2)))}}

In the general case it has three different roots. Now
Solve[CharacteristicPolynomial[A, x] == 0, x] /. rule


{{x -> 0}, {x -> 0}, {x -> 14}}

has a root of multiplicity 2 (not the generic case). This makes the difference. Let us verify that reasoning.
FindInstance[1/2 (a11 + a33 + 
 a12 h - \[Sqrt]((a11 + a33 + a12 h)^2 + 
    4 (a13^2 - a11 a33 - a12 a33 h + a13^2 h^2))) == 0, {a11, a12, a13, a33, h}, Reals, 2]


{{a11 -> 147, a12 -> 82, a13 -> -67, a33 -> 80,  h -> (3280 - 3 Sqrt[4821991])/4489}, {a11 -> -131, a12 -> -27,  a13 -> 55, a33 -> 2205, h -> (-11907 - Sqrt[506729])/1210}}

and
rule = {a11 -> 147, a12 -> 82, a13 -> -67, a33 -> 80, 
   h -> (3280 - 3 Sqrt[4821991])/4489};
A = {{a11, a12, a13}, h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}};
{a, b} = JordanDecomposition[A];
N[(b /. rule)] // MatrixForm
B = A /. rule;
{a1, b1} = JordanDecomposition[B];
N[b1 // MatrixForm]

demonstrates the same phenomenon.
Addition. The same issue and explanation  with MatrixMinimalPolynomial.
MatrixMinimalPolynomial[a_List?MatrixQ, x_] := 
Module[{i, n = 1, qu = {}, 
mnm = {Flatten[IdentityMatrix[Length[a]]]}}, 
While[Length[qu] == 0, AppendTo[mnm, Flatten[MatrixPower[a, n]]];
qu = NullSpace[Transpose[mnm]];
n++]; First[qu] . Table[x^i, {i, 0, n - 1}]]

Compare
MatrixMinimalPolynomial[{{a11, a12, a13}, h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}}, x]


(-a13^2 + a11 a33 + a12 a33 h - a13^2 h^2) x + (-a11 - a33 -  a12 h) x^2 + x^3

which has three different roots in the general case with
MatrixMinimalPolynomial[{{a11, a12, a13}, 
h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}} /. 
{a11 -> 1, a12 -> 4,  a13 -> 3, h -> 2, a33 -> 5}, x]


-14 x^2 + x^3

The latter has 0 as a root of multiplicity 2. As we see, it coincides with CharacteristicPolynomial[{{a11, a12, a13},  h {a11, a12, a13}, {a13, h a13, a33}} /.  {a11 -> 1, a12 -> 4,  a13 -> 3, h -> 2, a33 -> 5}, x] . Also MatrixMinimalPolynomial[A,x] coincides with  CharacteristicPolynomial[A,x]

I just want to note, that for Jordan decomposition important polynomial is not characteristic polynomial, but so called "minimal polynomial". Strictly speaking if minimal polynomial have a root with multiplicity higher than 1, that means Jordan decomposition will have nontrivial block. Multiplicity >1 of roots of characteristic polynomial in general don't ensure existence of nontrivial Jordan block, since it can also mean multiple eigenvalue. However it is well known fact that minimal polynomial divides characteristic polynomial.

Look at https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixMinimalPolynomial.html how to compute matrix minimal polynomial. Also I remember that Daniel Lichtblau (?) wrote a function to compute this polynomial in a more efficient way.  I also remembered that special solutions (non generic) has measure zero in so called Zariski topology. Simply speaking almost all solution are generic one.

@Acus: Thank you for your valuable comment. See the addition to my answer.

@Acus: Thank you for your personal opinion. Frankly saying, I I don't understand your " however, I think, it provides only partial simplification, not full solution". Can you elaborate it (Pronouns are so misleading..)? I think MatrixMinimalPolynomial produces a generic result for  a symbolic matrix.

@Acus: Sorry,  I still don't understand how your long comments are related to my answer. Do you see  a defect in the answer? If so, please clearly and exactly state that defect.

No defect. It is my problem since I can't understand why JordanDecomposition with symbolic entries can be useful. From my point of view it can't precisely because for symbolic input minimal polynomial coincides withe the characteristic polynomial. And characteristic polynomial is useless for Jordan decomposition, And I am simply  seeking a situation/example where  Symbolic Jordan decomposition can be useful (since a few articles I red on the subject simply didn't provide any example). No further comments.
